# Why When i try to open a link using object id then it's not working in django 3.2?

Tags: python, django

I am using django 3.2 and i am trying to learn how i can print models.py data on my html page. During this i wanted to add a href tag on home page that will redirect to about page with object id and display the other details. But it's not working.

#### App Name is greeting_app

##### greeting_app/urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('/about/<int:pk>/', views.about, name="about"),
]
```

##### greeting_app/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.enums import Choices

# Create your models here.
gender_choice = (
    ("0", "Nothing"),
    ("1", "Male"),
    ("2", "Female"),
)

class basicinformation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choice, max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

##### greeting_app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import basicinformation

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    information = basicinformation.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"info":information})

def about(request, id):
    data = basicinformation.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'about.html', {"data":data})
```

Comment: Where do you render that link? Can you provide the relevant parts of the `insex.html` template?

Comment: i haven't used it yet in index.html i just wanted to make sure it's working by directly inputting /about/object.id in the urls. for example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/1

Comment: what if you use `127.0.0.1:8000/about/1/`, so with a trailing slash?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i still get the same error using trailing slash. here is the screen shot of error that i am getting. please have a look https://ibb.co/86d2w3r

Comment: @BhaweshChaudhary you did not append the trailing slash on your screenshot.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please show me the code to understand it better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

path('about/int:id/', views.about, name="about"),

Comment: Yes thank you! I did the same few minutes ago and it worked and i also submitted the answer as well. :)

Comment: Yup most of our mistakes comes from where we less expect. Good luck to your project.

Answer (score 1):

#### In greeting_app/urls.py

I simply removed the / before about and changed pk to id and it worked.

 From this

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('/about/<int:pk>/', views.about, name="about"),
]
```

to this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('about/<int:id>/', views.about, name="about"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
path('/about/<int:pk>/', views.about, name="about"),
```

to

```py
path('/about/<int:id>/', views.about, name="about"),
```

In `views.about`, you attempted to get `id` as a parameter, but in `urls.py`, the primary key is passed as `pk` (`<int:pk>`) not `id`.

Comment: Hello there! I did exactly what you said but i am still getting the error. here is the link of error page. https://ibb.co/KWtKRTD